# Не могу скопировать элемент

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Есть один **[сайт](https://filmora.wondershare.com/)**, понравилась на нем кнопка Browse, попытался скопировать стили, вроде получилось, выглядит так же, но самая главная фишка этой кнопки - эффект при наведении почему то не работает... пробовал сперва вручную все копировать, а также с помощью расширения SnappySnipet - но эффект практически один, выглядит также, но при наведении не анимируется, помогите разобраться почему так

```css
#A_1 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(49, 60, 72);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(49, 60, 72);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 124.922px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(49, 60, 72);
    perspective-origin: 62.4531px 25px;
    transform-origin: 62.4531px 25px;
    caret-color: rgb(49, 60, 72);
    background: rgb(97, 222, 208) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(97, 222, 208);
    font: normal normal 700 normal 18px / 50px markpro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 12.5px 10px;
    outline: rgb(49, 60, 72) none 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}/*#A_1*/

#A_1:before {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(49, 60, 72);
    content: '""';
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 37.4531px;
    opacity: 0.08;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.015625px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(49, 60, 72);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 87.4531px;
    z-index: 1;
    column-rule-color: rgb(49, 60, 72);
    perspective-origin: 43.7188px 25px;
    transform-origin: 43.7188px 25px;
    caret-color: rgb(49, 60, 72);
    border-top: 0px none rgb(49, 60, 72);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(49, 60, 72);
    border-bottom: 50px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font: normal normal 700 normal 18px / 50px markpro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(49, 60, 72) none 0px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}/*#A_1:before*/
```

```html
<a href="#" id="A_1">Browse</a>
```

И еще почему расширение это таким странным образом стили копирует? скорее создает, должно быть целая куча а после применения расширения только два стиля, но все работает так же, что за чудо группировка стилей?

Comment: там же просто при `hover` сдвигается градиент и всё

Comment: я это понял, но почему он на сайте сдвигается а если стили скопировать то нет, ни здесь ни на js fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это все можно сделать намоного проще

```css
.button {
  padding: 30px 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #555;
}

.button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 50%, transparent 0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 1s background;
}

.button:hover:before {
  background-position: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Скачать</div>
```

Comment: вот за это лойс)

Comment: подскажите только зачем здесь  position:relative; ? ведь и без него все прекрасно работает?

Comment: Случайно добавил

Comment: @Duoxx  там же ведь по другому сделано смещение градиента !

Comment: Какая разница??

Comment: @Duoxx разница в том что - разверни градиент как в примере .. увидешь

Comment: Не нужно ничего разворачивать

Comment: @Duoxx  в примере не так а вот так :https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/NMdwLY?editors=0100

Comment: Что не так, все как надо.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76746/discussion-between---and-duoxx).